# Methods to stop jolting in a spring powered projectile launcher

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Situation: A machine, similar to an exercise bike which is seen in modern gyms, relies on the input power through pedals via a human. A reduction ratio leads to a mutilated pinon which is used to drive back a rack which the compressive spring is attached to. As the displacement of the linear spring increases, so does the force in the spring. Eventually, when the rack is released from the mutilated pinion, it slides forward and the force in the spring becomes 0 again (as displacement is now also zero). This abrupt change in the force in the spring is bound to cause some jolting motion for the person pedalling.

Question: Are there any (relatively simple) methods of reducing this effect that this jolting motion has on the rider. I've already done some research and have found that a common solution is some sort of fly wheel. However, I'm struggling to understand how this will reduce the jolt that the rider experiences.

Any help is much appreciated, please let me know if the solution requires further explanation.

Comment: Are you interested in reducing the effect A) from the release of the force, or B) from the impact of the rack? They are two different things. It would also help if you could provide a sketch, or some basic quantities (typical forces, spring constant etc).

Comment: @NMech I'm interested in reducing the jolt from the release of the force. I'll include some sketches and quantities and edit my question.

Comment: Fly wheel and Free body hub?

Comment: Sounds like you want a basic shock absorber to dampen the rebound.